# Does QLPreviewController support in iOS 10 BMP files?

Tags: bmp, ios10, qlpreviewcontroller

Has anybody tried to view BMP files in QLPreviewController? 
In my case same app, same code, same file is showing in iOS9.x but not in iOS10. This happens in Simulator as well as on real devices.

Has anybody experienced this?

iOS9: OK
[image: Working in iOS9]

iOS10: Failed
[image: Failed in iOS10]

The file is in XCode visible (in debuggerview) File size is recognized. But not displayed.

Any ideas?